# C++ Template: Kind of like infinite recursion but not really

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>

template <uint32_t test_value, uint32_t ...Vn>
struct is_prime_tmpl;

template <uint32_t test_value>
struct is_prime_tmpl<test_value> {
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <uint32_t test_value, uint32_t V1, uint32_t ...Vn>
struct is_prime_tmpl<test_value, V1, Vn...> {
    static constexpr bool value = (test_value % V1 != 0) && is_prime_tmpl<test_value, Vn...>::value;
};

template <uint32_t ...Vn>
struct prime {};

template <uint32_t max_target, uint32_t test_value, class PrimeList>
struct generate_prime_helper_tmpl;

template <uint32_t max_target, uint32_t test_value, uint32_t ...Vn>
struct generate_prime_helper_tmpl<max_target, test_value, prime<Vn...>> {
    static constexpr auto result = test_value <= max_target ? 
            (is_prime_tmpl<test_value, Vn...>::value ? 
                generate_prime_helper_tmpl<max_target, test_value + 1, prime<Vn..., test_value>>::result :                  generate_prime_helper_tmpl<max_target, test_value + 1, prime<Vn...>>::result) :
            prime<Vn...>();
};

int main() {
    static_assert(is_prime_tmpl<2>::value);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<generate_prime_helper_tmpl<2, 2, prime<>>::result, prime<2>);
}
```

The code is trying to generate a sequence of prime numbers.  But it fails to compile on my local machine with g++10.  The compiler doesn't emit any warning nor error.  It just compiles forever.

It seems like the recursion is broken somehow.  But I fail to see it.  I am more interested in what goes wrong than the actual solution.

Any idea what has gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ternary operator does *not* stop recursion, which makes your code fall into infinite recursion. You should use `if constexpr` to prevent recursion when the argument does not meet the condition.

Something like this:

```
template <uint32_t max_target, uint32_t test_value, uint32_t ...Vn>
struct generate_prime_helper_tmpl<max_target, test_value, prime<Vn...>> {
  static constexpr auto result = [] {
    if constexpr (test_value <= max_target) {
      if constexpr (is_prime_tmpl<test_value, Vn...>::value)
        return generate_prime_helper_tmpl<max_target, test_value + 1, prime<Vn..., test_value>>::result;
      else
        return generate_prime_helper_tmpl<max_target, test_value + 1, prime<Vn...>>::result;
    }
    else
      return prime<Vn...>();
  }();
};
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/449qdrzEs)

Comment: Thanks for your interesting solution. I thought by declaring `result` as `constexpr`, it will force the compiler to evaluate the whole expression in compile time, but it seems like the compiler is trying to expand the code without evaluating the ternary operation....

Comment: @HCSF - Of course it does. Evaluating the expression requires two well formed operands, even if one is not used.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica so you are saying because when compiler sees the ternary operator, it doesn't try to evaluate the condition expression first but the compiler will try to evaluate the two operands first, and so it becomes an infinite recursion, and with `if constexpr`, compiler will evaluate the condition expression first?

Comment: @HCSF - Nope. The compiler doesn't evalute the conditional. This recursion happens way before evaluation. The conditional is parsed, and its two operands must be some entities that can appear in a conditional. So the compiler has no choice but to instantiate them to see if they are even valid operands. Rinse and repeat.